# Bash int variable problem with using in awk

Tags: awk

I have two files, fisrt "file.txt" have few lines, next file: "output.txt is empty", examples:

```
    cat file.txt

Line1     x   i   12gb
Line2     x   u   13.7gb
Line3     x   q   4.3gb
Line4     x   t   33gb
Line5     f   t   29.04gb
Line6     f   t   38gb
```

```
cat output.txt
```

I need to grep lines only where size is greater than 30 and separate size, f.e. 29.04gb to 29.04 gb (with white char) but i have problem with my script (in awk):

```
#!/bin/bash

plik=file.txt
OUT=output.txt

awk '{if (30<=$2) print $1, $4}' $plik >$OUT
```

My output.txt file looks:

```
Line3 4.3gb
Line4 33gb
Line6 38gb
```

Can u tell me where is the problem with my awk line ?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Your question is much harder to understand because you don't show exactly the output you want given that input. I assume by `and separate size, f.e. 29.04gb to 29.04 gb (with white char)` you mean you want a blank char between the number and gb in  the output - if that's not chat you want then please clarify that statement.

Comment: It's confusing that in your code `if (30<=$2) print $1, $4` you know that the number you want to print is stored in $4 but you're testing the value of $2 instead of $4 to decide whether to print it or not. There must be some reason for that but I can't imagine what it'd be unless your real data doesn't actually look like the example you provided.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '$NF+0>30' Input_file
```

Simply checking condition if last field(where +0 will take till digits only in it) is greater than 30, if this condition is TRUE then print that line.

Comment: This command works. But what if i dont have my data size (f.e. 30.24gb) in last column ?
Example:

line1.file     30gb host1.new.york
line2.file3     29.8gb host2.new.jersey

The point is that I need to take only column 1 and 2 ($1 and $2) where size is greater than 30 (so we will take only 1st line) and then separate size from units parts. e.g. output in this case:

line1.file     30 gb

Comment: @seroslaw, Sorry this is not clear, as per your shown samples, my code is working fine. Please do let me know more clearly what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
Line1     x   i   12gb
Line2     x   u   13.7gb
Line3     x   q   4.3gb
Line4     x   t   33gb
Line5     f   t   29.04gb
Line6     f   t   38gb
```

then

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/([[:alpha:]]+$)/, " \\1", 1)}$4>=30{print $1, $4, $5}' file.txt
```

output

```
Line4 33 gb
Line6 38 gb
```

Explanation: I instruct AWK to look for letters (`[[:alpha:]]`) at end (`$`) of line and insert space before them, thus 4th column become number itself and 5th column `gb`, then when value in 4th column is less equal `30` I print 1st, 4th and 5th column.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're asking for:

```
$ awk '($NF+0)>30{sub(/[[:alpha:]]/," &",$NF); print $NF}' file.txt
33 gb
38 gb
```

or maybe:

```
$ awk '($NF+0)>30{sub(/[[:alpha:]]/," &",$NF); print $1, $NF}' file.txt
Line4 33 gb
Line6 38 gb
```